# Flask not printing request data

Tags: python, html, http, flask

I am new to flask and am following a tutorial online to create and run a simple web app. I have a login page and all I am trying to do is when the user hits the "Login" button I want the program to simply print out the "request.form" data. The problem is that the program only prints out the data once I manually make a change to auth.py.

login.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}Login{% endblock %} {% block content
    %}
    <form method="POST">
        <h3 align="center">Login</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <input
            type="email"
            class="form-control"
            id="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Enter email"
        />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input
                type="password"
                class="form-control"
                id="password"
                name="password"
                placeholder="Enter password"
            />
        </div>
        <br />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

auth.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, flash

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    data = request.form
    print(data) 
    return render_template("login.html", boolean=True)

# if you refresh/load page its a GET and if you send data its a POST
@auth.route('/sign-up', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    return render_template("sign_up.html") 

@auth.route('/logout')  
def logout():
    return "<p>Logout<p>"
```

This is the output I get when I click the login button.

```
 * Serving Flask app 'website'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with watchdog (fsevents)
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 906-382-173
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2023 16:36:36] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

This is the output I get after manually making a change in the auth.py file:

```
 * Detected change in '/PersonalProjects/flask template/website/auth.py', reloading
 * Detected change in '/PersonalProjects/flask template/website/auth.py', reloading
ImmutableMultiDict([('email', 's@m.com'), ('password', 'asd')])
 * Restarting with watchdog (fsevents)
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 906-382-173
```

Why is it that I have to manually make this change instead of the program just automatically printing out the email and password? This code seems to work fine for the person whose tutorial I am following so what can I do to fix this?

Comment: I would not expect Flask to automatically dump emails and plaintext passwords. That would be a security problem for one. If the tutorial didn't show them adding printing, they may have just glossed over that part.

Comment: @Carcigenicate They did show them adding printing like I have in my auth.py but for some reason for them it automatically reloads the program and prints it without them having to manually change anything.

Comment: It seems like python thinks that the print statement is at the top level of your file, outside the `login` function, which is why it's being called on server restart instead of on POST. Not sure what would be causing that, but maybe that gives you an idea on how to solve it. The only thing I could think of is improper indentation, it looks fine here but maybe it's different in your local version.

Comment: What do you mean? There's reflected the changed immediately, while you needed to restart the development server?